# Android Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho um projeto android antigo e pretendo dar vida nele.

baixei o android studio 2.0 importei meu projeto e nada funcionou

mensagem de erro.

```
14:22:37 Gradle sync failed: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in P:\AppData\Local\Android\Toobar\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.
         Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisará usar uma versão mais recente do gradle para fazer builds dos seus apps. Você está usando a versão 2.10 e está sendo solicitado a versão 2.2.

Eu não sei como estão as configurações na sua IDE, então, vou citar alguns lugares pra confirmar que está tudo OK.

Vá em File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home e confira se a opção "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" está marcada

Vá em File > Project Structure > Project e coloque a versão 2.2.1 no campo do "Gradle version".

Verifique se vai resolver. Qualquer coisa, comente aqui!

Comment: Boa noite meu amigo, Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Troquei a versão e funcionou corretamente
Vá em File > Project Structure > Project e coloque a versão 2.2.1 no campo do "Gradle version".

Answer (score 0):

No meu estava com o mesmo problema, fui no  File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home e confira se a opção "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" está marcada e estava ja correto, porem no File > Project Structure > Project e coloque a versão 2.2.1 no campo do "Gradle version", troquei e resolveu meu problema, valeu!!